# Why does blocking on UdpClient.Receive vastly increase cpu usage?

Tags: .net, performance, sleep, udpclient

I thought I'd optimize the following code because it `Sleep(1)`s when there is no data available and hence would incur a latency of up to 15.6 ms (the actual timer resolution on the box in production), and waste time sleeping, while it could be processing packets.

```
while (running)
{
  int available = _udpClient.Available;
  if (available > 0)
  {
    byte[] packet = _udpClient.Receive(ref serverEndPoint);
    _concurrentJobQueue.Enqueue(packet);
    if (available > x)
      LogSomething(available);
  }
  else
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
}
```

As `UdpClient` offers a blocking `Receive()` this looks easy enough:

```
while (running)
{
  byte[] packet = _udpClient.Receive(ref serverEndPoint);
  _concurrentJobQueue.Enqueue(packet);
  int available = _udpClient.Available;
  if (available > x)
    LogSomething(available);
}
```

Now `Receive()` should be doing all the sleeping, and if implemented efficiently, it would wake up immediately when a packet arrives.

This should

- be slightly less cpu intensive, as there is no unnecessary spinning (up to 1000 times/sec depending on the timer resolution)
- remove the latency of sleeping

However, when sending 100k packets at a rate of 10k per second, the "optimized" version is much more cpu intensive than the original - and the following results are from a test on a machine with a timer resolution of 1 ms, so the original version is "only" sleeping 1ms in case there are no packets available:

```
test case     avg cpu (%)
------------+------------
original      0.81427075
"optimized"   16.8082852
```

**Why would blocking on `Receive()` keep the cpu more than 20 times as busy?**

Notes:

- I double-checked that the number of processed packets is about the same in both cases, i.e. the reason that the optimized version consumes so much more cpu is NOT that the original version has less packets to process due to overflowing UDP buffers
- We have a total of 50 `UdpClient`s, and 1 thread for each `UdpClient` is running the above `while` loop
- Trying to profile the "optimized" version in Visual Studio makes the Virtual Box VM where the system is hosted on crash
- Testing on physical machines with different timer resolutions (1 or 15.6) shows qualitatively similar results
- Even on the box with 15.6ms timer resolution, the box has no trouble keeping up with the incoming packets and total processing time of the original version is the same as in the "optimized" case (I haven't checked the latency of individual packets, which is hard to do inside the app alone, because a `Sleep` would affect the time I'd create the "incoming timestamp")

Comment: You need to play with Perfmon.exe.  First one you ought to look at is the System + Context Switches/sec counter.

Comment: can you provide a full working example if it's not too much problem?